# iPhone photos messes up orientation in EXIF data

Tags: video, metadata, photo, exif

I am working on a projects where i have to take a LOT of photos and videos which I mainly use my iphone 14, both front and back camera. The problem I have is that the photos look fine on my device but when I upload it to certain places the orientation is messed up. the problem is in the EXIF data. FOr photos I can fix this easy by simply saving them again in photoshop, I don't have a solution for the videos yet. I really need to fix this at the source though because so much unnecessary time out of my schedule. How can I make sure my phone save these photos and files correctly so I don't have to deal with this in the "post production".

The main problem I have is that the images are rotated 270 degrees

Also a side question. I know how to fix the photos after they are taken but how do I fix the videos? I use powerdirector but it doesn't fix the problem.